# Is there a way in json-schema to validate object keys matching regex?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Is there a way to have the json schema validator to validate *keys* of a json object? For example:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": { // here properties is an object containing user-defined keys that should be alphanumeric or underscore.
        "values": {
            "type": "object",
            "patternProperties": {
                "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+": {
                    "description": "Foo"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So here's some examples of what should and shouldn't pass:

```
// Should pass:
{
 "values": {
   "myKey1": { "foo": 1 },
   "myKey2_": "bar"
 }
}

// Should fail but no error is shown saying this doesnt match schema:
{
  "values": {
    "m\1[]": 123
  }
}
```

I tried using `patternProperties` but anything that doesn't match my regex is just ignored, no validation error is thrown on the offending line.
This is consistent with documentation on patternProperties:
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#pattern-properties

Is there a way to do what i'm looking for? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `additionalProperties` to make an object invalid that doesn't pass the `patternProperties` you've required.

> By default any additional properties are allowed.

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "values": {
        "type": "object",
        "patternProperties": {
            "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+": {
                "description": "Foo"
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

↳ [JSON Schema : Additional Properties](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#additional-properties)

Comment: thanks for the help. that worked. a follow up question would be how do i add some custom validation message saying something like "this name is not of the format alphanumeric and underscore"?

Comment: @joeb. You're welcome! Regarding the custom message; json really doesn't do that. It's generally invalid or valid. Take a look at the `required` section of the docs (underneath the info already on that page) ~ cheers!